# nullpointer on PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to fetch my data from inside a dataprovider, since the dataprovider doesn't provide a context I've created following function:

```
public String getUN() {
    Log.w("app", "getUN");
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    Log.w("app", "getUN2");
    return prefs.getString("username", "");
}
```

I've used eclipse debugging (along with the Log messages) to find the point of the error: the preferencemanager-line

called from another class trough:

```
PreferencesActivity pa = new PreferencesActivity();
Log.w("app","user:"+pa.getUN());
```

(again Log for debugging)

Thanks.

edit: alternative method for fetching the data is also welcome,
data is stored using android's 'native' method (via preference xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass context to your data provider.

Comment: then I could just pass the uid & password aswell, if that's the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use, `getApplicationContext()`